# Extract number from string using pattern

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

Ok so this is what I have

> "C:\this\file\is\rev12\oh\A_12345\doll\classes"

I want to extract from this string the `12345` only.

How can it be done using Java  [Pattern.compile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile%28java.lang.String%29)?

Comment: i am using java, sorry forgot to mention

Comment: Might as well mention that what I want to do, is to be able to extract the number from the file A_12345. this file will always start with A_ and I must make sure to only grab this and not per example the 12 from the rev12 folder in the string.

Comment: Sorry, that is not enough information to build a pattern that works reliably. Does a grammar over the possible path patterns exists?

Answer (score 0):

You should define in more general idea how this number appears.
So if it somewhere in string with leading underscore `_` and trailing slash `\` pattern will be following `_(\d+)\\`.

Your number can be extracted from pattern matched group.
[Try it](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=_%28%5Cd%2b%29%5C%5C&input=C%3a%5Cthis%5Cfile%5Cis%5Crev12%5Coh%5CA_12345%5Cdoll%5Cclasses).

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code you could use, however I had to change the backward slash to forward slash in the path and use an absolute path. I also tried to change the path "C:\\this\\file\\is\\rev12\\oh\\A_12345\\doll\\classes" to use it in Windows. You could change the '\' to '\\'. Both the path string works for the below code.

```
File file = new java.io.File("C:/this/file/is/rev12/oh/A_12345/doll/classes").getAbsoluteFile();
    System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());

    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
    Matcher mat = pat.matcher(file.getAbsolutePath());
    while (mat.find()) {
      System.out.println(mat.group());
    }
```